# Extract specific string and change string format (jquery/ javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-extraction

I want to extract "10:30" from `mystring` and convert it to "10, 30".

```
var mystring = "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
```

Output will be:

```
Time: 10:30    
Changed Format: 10, 30
```

Provide code solution only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to extract the time:

```
var mystring = "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
var match = mystring.match(/(\d+:\d+):\d+/);
if (match) {
    var output = "Time: " + match[1].replace(":", ", ");
}
```

Comment: can u tell me about this format
"Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: @FARAZFRANK - It's a standard date/time format, what's your question?

Comment: @FARAZFRANK - and what is your question?

Comment: where can i find "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" this, linke documention or examples?

Comment: @FARAZFRANK - A couple links on the date format: http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.